# How to read names and grades from csv file and sort them in ascending order?

Tags: python

I want to sort the names and grades in ascending order in the loop below.. I want to write a program that reads the grades in ascending order with the name of each person from the csv file and prints it. But I have trouble writing the program in the for loop. Please help me write the program according to the output so that it works according to the output.

```
import csv
from statistics import mean

def cc():
    with open('reders.csv' , newline='') as csvfile:
        sep = csv.reader(csvfile)
        av = list()
        for row in sep:
            q = list()
            name = row[0]
            for i in row[1:]:
                qq = []
                q.append(int(i))
                b = float(mean(q))
                c = str(b)
                qq.append(c)
```

output correct:

```
ali,5.0
hamid,6.066666666666666
mandana,7.5
soheila,7.833333333333333
sara,9.75
sina,11.285714285714286
sarvin,11.375
```

Please help me complete the code according to the output. GPAs and names were already given to a file csv like this:

```
mandana, 5,7,3,15
hamid, 3,9,4,20,9,1,8,16,0,5,2,4,7,2,1
sina, 19,10,19,6,8,14,3
sara, 0,5,20,14
soheila, 13,2,5,1,3,10,12,4,13,17,7,7
ali, 1.9
sarvin, 0.16,16,13,19,2,17,8
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add sample input data to your question so folks can see if they can calculate the right values.

Comment: I edited my question. now please help me

Comment: Hey @alex, can you also properly format your source data and explain how you want to process it to obtain the output ? You're saying you want to list each person's grades in ascending order, but your output looks more like an average or computation of the grades themselves.

Comment: I want to take the names and grades of each person from the CSV file and calculate their grade point average and display the result in ascending order

Comment: Your input doesn't match what you call the "output correct". For example how could `ali` have a gpa for `5.0` when the input only has one score of `1.9`? You question is unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use more legible variable names. They help a lot in understanding what you're trying to do.

You should know that you need to complete these tasks:

1. Read the csv
2. Calculate the GPAs
3. Match the GPAs with their key
4. Sort the keys based on the GPA

If you're not sure, try writing out each step of your algorithm.

```
import csv
import operator
from statistics import mean

with open('reders.csv' , newline='') as csvfile:
    separators = csv.reader(csvfile)
    result = {}
    for line in separators:
        name = line[0]
        gpa = mean([float(item) for item in line[1:]])
        result[name] = gpa
    sorted_results = dict( sorted(result.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1)))
    print(sorted_results)
```

Output:

```
{'ali': 1.9, 'hamid': 6.066666666666666, 'mandana': 7.5, 'soheila': 7.833333333333333, 'sara': 9.75, 'sarvin': 10.737142857142857, 'sina': 11.285714285714286}
```

EDIT: I'm seeing that your code isn't exactly what you say you need, but the example I'm providing should be enough guidance.